# DatePicker does not display the date in input when editing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//Set new date

```
this.state.startDate = new Date("July 27, 1962 23:30:00")
const date = new Date(this.state.startDate);
```

//Set hours

```
date.setHours(0, 0, this.state.second);
date.toTimeString();
```

When I click `edit`. I want this date to be displayed in the input. And that it can be edited

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbp1S.jpg

Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cuubsx

**Edit**

```
class Edit extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.props.startDate}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

**Item**

```
class Item extends Component {

  state = {
    startDate: new Date("July 27, 1962 23:30:00"),
    second: 120
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }


  render() {

    const date = new Date(this.state.startDate);
    console.log(date)
    date.setHours(0, 0, this.state.second);
    date.toTimeString();

    return (
         <Edit
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            startDate={date}
            handleDescription={this.handleDescription}
            date = {this.date} 
          />

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. When you are using `customInput`, you are not specifying
a `onChange` handler, so selecting a date does not update anything. So add a `onChange` handler:

```
<input onClick={this.props.onClick} onChange={this.props.onChange}
className="dateInput" value={this.props.value} type="text" />
```

And you are passing `this.date` as a prop to `EditForm`, which should be `date` instead.
As `this.date` is undefined, your date input is always blank.

```
<EditForm
    handleChange={this.handleChange}
    description={this.state.description}
    startDate={date}
    handleDescription={this.handleDescription}
    onSave={this.onSave}
    onCancel={this.onCancel}
    date={date}
/>
```

The result is in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3rmbqt).

Comment: If you have any other queries comment below. It it resolves your issue you can accept the answer.

Comment: If you choose new time. New time doesn't display in input

Comment: If you choose new time, example 00:30 --> should display 00:30, not 00:32; example : 2:30 --> should display 2:30, not 2:32

Comment: And what about the second? if second is set to 125, what should it show?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found your mistake.

`index.js` line 29:

```
<DatePicker
          selected={this.props.date}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
          showTimeSelect
          customInput={<CustomInput />}
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          value={this.props.startDate}
          dateFormat="yy-MM-dd, hh:mm"
          timeCaption="time"
        />
```

`value` should be `selected`

Fix: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p7czys

For reference see the documentation: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-43

Comment: In input should display `July 27, 1962 00:02`

Comment: Then change  `dateFormat="yy-MM-dd, hh:mm"`  to what you want?

Comment: No. 'date' from here `const date = new Date(this.state.startDate);
    console.log(date)
    date.setHours(0, 0, this.state.second);
    date.toTimeString();` display in input and edit

Comment: You can change the representation in the input by changing `dateFormat`.

Comment: I understand `dateFormat="yy-MM-dd, HH:mm"`. But If I click choose hours, 'hours' don't change in input. always is 00:02. I click 00:15 replace 00:02 in input

Comment: @Umbro The call to `setHours` always resets the time, no matter what you input + `this.state.second` is 120 and `setHours(0, 0, 120)` is equivalent to `setHours(0, 2, 0)` (120 seconds is 2 minutes), which is why it is always there. Remove that call and use `this.state.startDate` directly in what you send to the Edit component to change that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code

1. In `Todo` component, you are passing `date={this.date}` which is wrong. `this.date` is `undefined`. You probably mean to pass only `date`. i.e. `date={date}`.
2. You are modifying the time in the parent component render function, which is executed every time you change something on input. So, either remove it or move it somewhere other than render method,

```
   date.setHours(0, 0, this.state.second);
```

Working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qnlbq9?embed=1&file=index.js

So, basically you are passing same value with two different props - `startDate` and `date`.

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky I had writen it earlier and found it in my old project.

**DateInput.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

class DateInput extends Component {
    setDate = date => {
        this.props.onChange(this.props.name, date);
    };

    render() {
       const { name, value } = this.props;
       return (
           <DatePicker
           id={name}
           name={name}
           selected={value}
           onChange={this.setDate}
         />
       );
    }
}

export default DateInput;
```

**App.js** (How to use it)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import DateInput from './DateInput';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data : {
       dateToday : new Date()
       //other properties
    }
  }
  handleDate = (name, date) => {
      const data = this.state.data;
      data[name] = date;
      this.setState({ data });
    };

  render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    return (
       <DateInput
       name="dateToday"
       value={data.dateToday}
       onChange={this.handleDate}
       />
    );
  }
}
```

**Important:** `name` is a `string` (key) of your variable, `value` is the `new Date()` (value) of your variable.

See Demo [here on CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-datepicker-set-date-example-4g1n7)

Comment: It sets both time & date :-)